# ediff broken on emacs 27.1?

Tags: ediff

I had no problem with ediff for years (decades, actually). However, a couple of years ago it started behaving badly. I'm not sure exactly when, but possibly when I started using Ubuntu. I'm now mostly on Ubuntu 22.04, with:

```
GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.33, cairo version 1.16.0)
 of 2023-08-16, modified by Debian
```

The problem is that the region highlights frequently misbehave if one of the regions is empty. The empty region is generally not shown, and you can't tell where it is. Advancing to the next region may not work; I generally have to `j` back and try again. Is this a known problem? I have this on 3 different Ubuntu 22.04 installs at the moment, and it makes life very difficult.

Comment: Can you reproduce it if you start with `emacs -Q`? If not, something in your init file(s) is causing it.

Comment: @NickD: yes, still there with `-Q`.

Comment: I don't think I can reproduce this, but maybe the files I'm trying to use are not complex enough. Can you provide a couple of example files that exhibit the problem? The shorter the better and if you can include them in your question that would be best, but if not, a pastebin somewhere should be OK as well.

Comment: @NickD: that's above&beyond, thanks. I prepared two files, but then found something interesting. It *does* work if I explicitly set the focus (click) back to the main window, and swap focus between the ediff box and the main window occasionally. So a Gnome issue? If the first diff is a missing region, for example, the main window shows the wrong part of the code, and doesn't show the region till the window is clicked. Do you still want the files?

Comment: @NickD: https://pastebin.com/Kg5PnmEA, and https://pastebin.com/MfjFvXU4

Comment: Yes, thanks: I will try them out tonight.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QJEN.png) is what the first diff (1/5) looks like for me - the empty region on the right is clearly marked. All the other diffs work as well. Maybe you can add a screenshot of a non-working diff?